# How to display condition based values out of SQL query result?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, bids

I have a simple query that returns a table. One of the columns gives a long string of characters with some repeatable text string which I want to remove prior rendering the table result content. There will be a clear indication which characters shall be cut off from the left side of the text string.

Shall I use expression within a graphic table or modify my query?
What kind of statement shall be used for that purpose?

Thank you

Comment: Show the query, show the table, show the string with the repeatable text string, and show what you want it to look like after.

Comment: You'll want to get into substring and potentially regex functions.  These vary database to database, so in addition to the info dfundako is ask for, you'll also need to tell us what database you are using

Answer (score 0):

modify your query with REPLACE function in sql.

```
SELECT REPLACE('YourString','CharacterToBeReplaced','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all suggestions. It is an easy database select that produce simple table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
TEAM,
SUBJECT,
COUNT(*) COUNT
FROM DATABASE
WHERE Subject not like '%TEST%' 
GROUP By Team, Subject
```

I have successfully cut off initial characters rendered in Subject field by adding expression to a table field in Visual Studio `=Replace(Fields!Subject.Value,"DUMMY-INFO", "")`.
Now the text rendered, begins with initial space I need to remove as well. Your suggestions will be valuable. Thank you!